# ScrollView jumps to the top of the page when change button backgroundImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uibutton

ScrollView jumps to the top of the page when I click a button at the bottom of the page. It also happens when I click on a uitexfield always at the bottom of the page. What can I do to make it stand still?
In viewDidLoad():

```
self.scrollView.pagingEnabled=NO;
```

in iewDidLayoutSubviews:

```
  -(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
       [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

   self.scrollView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
   self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(SCREEN_WIDTH, 1150);


 }
```

The problem is while change ImageBackground of the button here:

```
 - (IBAction)pressedData:(id)sender {


   if ( !self.checkDataIsPressed ) {
        self.checkData =true;
        [self.checkDataPerson setBackgroundImage:
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"check_on"]forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //the jumps scrollview is here
   }else{
        self.checkData =false;
       [self.checkDataPerson setBackgroundImage:
       [UIImage imageNamed:@"check_off"]forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //the jumps scrollview is here
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the view did layout subview method for,,

Comment: Is a uiscrollview with dynamic height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on button Click

```
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(320,0) animated:YES];
```